# How can we get more trusted users available to review close votes?

Tags: discussion

I've noticed that close votes seem to have an endless backlog. On other SEs, this does not seem to happen as engaged users that stick around end up with the 3k rep needed to review these questions.

Given the amount of blatantly off-topic questions we get, it seems to me that we need more high rep users. It also seems to me that WPSE users are not too fond of upvotes which may be holding some otherwise helpful users back from fully contributing.

What, if anything, can we do to resolve these issues?

Comment: It's the same on Drupal Answers. Usually the diamonds close them then. Would be nice if the threshold could be lowered to three maybe?

Comment: Didn't StackOverflow lower the threshold to 3 community member votes? Can this be applied to WP.SE?

Comment: I'd support this proposal.

Comment: I've added a proposal for this, https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4737/motion-to-have-the-close-vote-threshold-lowered-to-3

Comment: FWIW I got downhearted at the tide of WooCommerce questions.  Perhaps just a few more of us putting in the effort will also help.  I'm in favour of lowering the threshold too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best way to do this is to have the close threshold lowered to 3.

1. Post a dedicated question for the community to see about lowering it to 3 (having a mod feature it wouldn't hurt)
2. Hopefully you get some consensus
3. If/when you do get consensus, have a moderator tag it [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) so Community Managers see it

[Here's an example of what that looks like](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1478/55930)