# Motion to have the close vote threshold lowered to 3

Tags: discussion, status-completed, vote-to-close

Related to the discussion [How can we get more trusted users available to review close votes?](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4731/how-can-we-get-more-trusted-users-available-to-review-close-votes), I motion that we should have the close vote threshold lowered from 5 to 3. With the lower threshold we could have off-topic questions closed faster and not have the cast votes age away for nothing. [This has already been done in SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/391832/we-re-lowering-the-close-reopen-vote-threshold-from-5-to-3-for-good).

Vote up for yay, down for nay.

Comment: I'd be in favour of this

Comment: I support this initiative!

Comment: Btw I've just went through the close vote queue, and a lot of them were at 3 or 4 votes. So I think this will really benefit this stack. Of the 20 questions probably more than 50% would already have been closed with the lower threshold.

Comment: I'm on board. It's a pain seeing a clearly off topic question hang around for days or weeks due to lack of votes, when the user could benefit from knowing that they're not likely to get an answer sooner.

Comment: Would the threshhold for re-opening also lower to 3?

Comment: @Flimm Yes, this is mentioned in Catija's post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As kero pointed out my post on MSE - [Testing three-vote close and reopen on 13 network sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364007/testing-three-vote-close-and-reopen-on-13-network-sites) (it's linked in the featured on meta sidebar) - we've finally got this project under way and WordPress is one of the sites we'll be running the test on.

Starting tomorrow, I'll be changing the site setting and closing and reopening will require only three votes. This test will run for 45 days and will be turned back to five votes to close and reopen while I review the data from the 13 sites. After we've seen the impact, I'll be posting results and, if there aren't negative impacts, we will change the setting to three permanently.

A few weeks into this, I'll be posting a question here on meta to ask for your thoughts about this change, so you will have an opportunity to discuss the impact.

Thank you so much for your patience while we got this prioritized and scheduled. There's a lot more information in the MSE post, so please review it.

Comment: Mostly leaving this here so y'all have an "official" statement and can ping me if you have any questions or thoughts. :)

Answer (score 2):

It is happening!

Today [it was announced on Meta StackExchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364007/testing-three-vote-close-and-reopen-on-13-network-sites?cb=1) that starting on **Thursday, May 6th**, 13 sites will have the close vote threshold lowered to 3 **for 45 days**. WPSE is one of this sites.

Comment: This is great! I've been waiting to hear the news about this.